# Characteristic function evaluated at $2\pi$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a real random variable with characteristic function $\phi$. Then 
\begin{align}
\phi(2\pi) = Ee^{i2\pi X} = E((e^{i\pi})^2)^X = E((-1)^2)^X = 1.
\end{align}
There have to be something wrong with the procedure because that equality is not true when, for example, $X\sim N(0,1)$ or $X\sim U(-1,1)$. (In those laste cases $\phi(t)=e^{-t^2/2}$ and $\phi(t)=\sin(t)/t$.)

Can someone help me clear my mistake?

Comment: identity $e^{ab} = (e^{a})^b$ isn't in general true when $a \in \mathbb C$ or $b \in \mathbb C$. Not to mention, that $e^{ab}$ is always a single value even when $a,b$ are complex, but when $a$ is complex and $b$ real (if it is complex, things can get even worse) then $(e^{a})^b$ can take many values, for example $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ has $2$ branches

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks, I found that it is true for $X\in\mathbb{Z}$, but not in general as you say.